# Square Roots of Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following vector function:

$$
r(t)=(t-\sinh t\cosh t)\,\partial_x+2\cosh t\,\partial_y.
$$

I computed its velocity to be as such:

$$
r'(t)=-2\sinh^2t\,\partial_x+2\sinh t\,\partial_y.
$$

Therefore, its speed is as follows:

$$
v(t)=2\sinh t\cosh t.
$$

However, when I computed this using Maple, the program (after simplifying) gave me this:

$$
v(t)=2\sqrt{\sinh^2t\cosh^2t}.
$$

Why did it not get rid of the radical?

**Edit**: Here is the Maple code:

[image]

Comment: Let's look in the Maple code.

Comment: Does Maple assume that $t$ is complex by default?  It may avoid reducing the square root in case $t$ has an imaginary part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the speed is $$ 2 \; \cosh t \; \; | \sinh t |  $$